# Crawl only HTML page while checking the response header

Tags: java, web-crawler

I am trying to get all the url's that have header as Content-Type:text/html so I am checking the response header of each url and If they have content-type: text/html, then I want to print that url that has content-type:text/html. But in my code when I am checking that if the header has Content-Type, it is not displaying anything.. And If I remove the if loop then it prints every link related to that particular url that I want to crawl and their response header..

```
public class MyCrawler extends WebCrawler {

    Pattern filters = Pattern.compile(".*(\\.(css|js|bmp|gif|jpe?g"
            + "|png|tiff?|mid|mp2|mp3|mp4" + "|wav|avi|mov|mpeg|ram|m4v|pdf"
            + "|rm|smil|wmv|swf|wma|zip|rar|gz))$");


    /*
    Pattern filters = Pattern.compile("(\\.(html))");
*/
    public MyCrawler() {
    }

    public boolean shouldVisit(WebURL url) {
        String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase();
        //System.out.println("Href: " +href);
        /*
        if (filters.matcher(href).matches()) {
            return false;
        }*/
        if (href.startsWith("http://www.somehost.com/")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void visit(Page page) {

        int docid = page.getWebURL().getDocid();

        String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();         
        String text = page.getText();
        List<WebURL> links = page.getURLs();
        int parentDocid = page.getWebURL().getParentDocid();


        //HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);


        try {
            URL url1 = new URL(url);
            URLConnection connection = url1.openConnection();

            Map responseMap = connection.getHeaderFields();
      for (Iterator iterator = responseMap.keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) 
     {
                String key = (String) iterator.next();
                if(key==("Content-Type")) //(Anything wrong with this if loop)
                {
                System.out.print(key + " = ");

                List values = (List) responseMap.get(key);
                for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
                    Object o = values.get(i);
                    System.out.print(o + ", ");
                }
                System.out.println("");
System.out.println(url1);
                }

            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //System.out.println("Docid: " + docid);
        //System.out.println("URL: " + url);
        //System.out.println("Text length: " + text.length());
        //System.out.println("Number of links: " + links.size());
        //System.out.println("Docid of parent page: " + parentDocid);
        System.out.println("=============");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **key** variable contains:

`Content-Type=[text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1]`

and therefor can't be caught with `==` or `.equals("Content-Type")`

If you try to run the following code, see what it prints out

```
URLConnection connection = url1.openConnection();

Map responseMap = connection.getHeaderFields();
Iterator iterator = responseMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
    String key = iterator.next().toString();
    if (key.contains("Content-Type"))
    {
        System.out.println(key);
        // Content-Type=[text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1]
        if (filters.matcher(key) != null){
            System.out.println(url1);
            // http://google.com
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Content-Type=[text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1]
http://google.com
```

It looks like you could also just do with one if statement as following:

```
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
    String key = iterator.next().toString();
    if (key.contains("text/html"))
    {
        System.out.println(url1);
        // http://google.com
    }
}
```

BTW string comparison in Java [is very intuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus), gets me all the time!

Comment: thanks for the example also.. :) And If I want the urls whose content-types are other than text/html. Then what can be done. As here we are checking for html by this `if (key.contains("text/html"))`.

Comment: Yes if you want to find something other than html, you can write if (key.contains("image/png")).  Or use filters.matcher(key) where filters contains the allowed content types

Answer (score 0):

For string comparison, use `.equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with

```
if (key != null && key.equals("Content-Type"))
```